# Algorithm to minimize the cost for mechanic

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, greedy

There is one straight road. And on some distance some job is present. And every job has some importance.

Now, mathematically, an array of locations is given to us, `location[]`. and there importance array is given, `importance[]`.

If you move from one point to other, mechanic needs to walk, and do job at that location.

And, mechanic needs to do all jobs.

We need to minimize summation of (importance*distance).

Example for better understanding :-

```
position     :-  1    6    12   13    14      24
importance   :-  1    2    10   3     5       1
```

If we start from 6, and move in following way

```
  6  -->   12 --->  13 ---> 14 --> 1 --> 24
```

= (10*6) + (3*7) + (5*8) + (1*21) + (1*44) = 186

If we move in following way,

```
12 --> 13  --> 14 -->  6 --> 1 --> 24
```

= (3*1) + (5*2) + (2*10) + (1*15) + (1*38)  = 86

```
So the minimum answer is 86
```

**My approach**

First we need to calculate from where we need to start. For that find **center of gravity**.

For position = 1, (5*2) + (11*10) + (12*3) + (13*5) + (23*1) = 244

For position = 6, (5*1) + (6*10) + (7*3) + (8*5) + (18*1) =  144.

Similarly calculate for all positions, and choose minimum value, i.e., `Center of gravity`.

But after choosing that point, how to move to other positions, is out of reach for me.

But I am not able to complete the algorithm. Please help in that.

Comment: Can you tell me, what is wrong with my algo ?

Comment: You only showed us half an algorithm, so we can't really tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: You sure the problem formulation is correct? I would have expected that the cost would be the sum of `importance * waiting_time`. Were `waiting_time` is the sum of all distances travelled before visting that position. In your formulation it is only the distance traveled since the last postion.

Comment: @Stefen Yes you are right. See the example, it shows the same that you said.

Comment: @devnull read @Dukeling 's link, specifically Rob Teller's answer describing going from `v1 -> v2 -> v3` vs `v1 -> v3 -> v2`.

Comment: @Dukeling I was  totally chocked in this problem. The thing that I know is to find the point from where we can start. But i am not sure whether above method will work or not.

Comment: @devnull: I don't think greedy works here, so I guess your approach will not give you an optimal solution

Comment: if your dataset is small enough then you can still try all combinations and use the best (N< 10..20) also as I understand importance is a simplifying weight (probably based on job frequency and material movement costs) so the real optimum can be different then the computed one (if the weights are not calculated very very carefully).

Comment: anyone have a proof why we should start from centre of gravity?